# Passing some values as variables

Tags: python, function

I'm a physics graduate student with some basic knowledge of Python and I'm facing some problems that challenge my abilities.

I'm trying to pass some variables as dummies and some not. I have a function that receives a function as the first argument, but I need that some values to be declared "a posteriori".

What I'm trying to mean is the following:

```
lead0 = add_leads(lead_shape_horizontal(W, n), (0, 0, n), sym0)
```

The function "add_leads" takes some function as well as a tuple and a third argument which is fine. But **n** hasn't any definition yet. I want that **n** has an actual sense when it enters "add_leads".

Here is the actual function add_leads

```
def add_leads(shape, origin_2D, symm):
        lead_return = []
        lead_return_reversed = []
        for m in range(L):
            n = N_MIN + m
            origin_3D = list(origin_2D)+[n]
            lead_return.append(kwant.Builder(symm))
            lead_return[m][red.shape(shape(n), tuple(origin_3D))] = ONN + HBAR*OMEGA*n
            lead_return[m][[kwant.builder.HoppingKind(*hopping) for 
hopping in hoppings_leads]] = HOPP
            lead_return[m].eradicate_dangling()
```

Note that *n is defined under for*, so, I wish to put the value of n in **shape(n)** (in this case **leads_shape_horizontal** with a fixed value for W, not for n).

I need this to be this way because eventually the function which is the argument for **lead_shape** might have more than 2 input values but still just need to vary **n**

Can I achieve this in Python? If I can, How to do so?
Help will be really appreciated.
Sorry for my english!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `lead_shape_horizontal(W, n)` return a function? If it does not, your code is wrong, because then you cannot call `shape(n)`.

Comment: If the `n` in `add_leads(lead_shape_horizontal(W, n), (0, 0, n), sym0)` is not defined prior to that call, you will receive an error. If you simply want to pass a pointer to the function, you can do that by `add_leads(lead_shape_horizontal, (0, 0, n), sym0)` however, this will still error due to `(0, 0, n)`. The fact that `n` is not defined prior to this call is a problem.

Comment: Seems to me actually like it should be `def add_leads(shape, W, origin_2D, symm)` and then lower down `red.shape(shape(W, n), tuple(origin_3D))`. Which can be called via `lead0 = add_leads(lead_shape_horizontal, W, (0, 0), sym0)`

Answer (score 0):

You probably should pass in the function `lead_shape_horizontal`, not the function with argument `lead_shape_horizontal(W, n)`

Because the latter one will return the result of the function, not function object itself. Unless the return value is also a function, you'll get an error when you later call `shape(n)`, which is identical to `lead_shape_horizontal(W, n)(n)`

As for providing a fix value for W but not for n, you can either give W a default value in the function or just don't make it an argument

For example,

```
def lead_shape_horizontal(n, W=some_value):
    # do stuff
```

or If you always fix W, then it doesn't have to be an argument

```
def lead_shape_horizontal(n):
    W = some_value
    # do stuff
```

Also note that you didn't define n when calling function, so you can't pass in n to the `add_leads` function.

Maybe you have to construct the `origin_2D` inside the function

like `origin_2D = origin_2D + (n,)`

Then you can call the function like this `lead0 = add_leads(lead_shape_horizontal, (0, 0), sym0)`

See [Python Document](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) to understand how default value works.

Some advice: Watch out the order of arguments when you're using default value.

Also watch out when you're passing in mutable object as default value. [This is a common gotcha](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm)